# Why geom_line is not displaying correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running analysis in Bike Sharing (kaggle) dataset. Heres is a sample:

Head

```
     yr  mnth Ano     cnt
  <int> <int> <chr> <int>
1     0     1 2011    985
2     0     1 2011    801
3     0     1 2011   1349
4     0     1 2011   1562
5     0     1 2011   1600
```

Tail

```
    yr   mnth  Ano   cnt
  <int> <int> <chr> <int>
1     1    12 2012   2114
2     1    12 2012   3095
3     1    12 2012   1341
4     1    12 2012   1796
5     1    12 2012   2729
```

Where "cnt" means the number of bikes for each day. Every line is a day from 01/01/2011 to 12/12/2012

My goal was to analyse the cnt for each month from both 2011 and 2012; However, I keep getting this weird output:

[image: plot]

my code:

```
k<- bike_new %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mnth,y=cnt))+  geom_line();k
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add `group = Ano` to `aes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the sage advice from **@AllanCameron** add the `group` element as a factor, and as you have two years, you would need a color. Here the code using simulated data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
bike_new %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(mnth),y=cnt,group=factor(Ano),color=factor(Ano)))+
  geom_line()+
  xlab('month')+
  labs(color='Ano')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
bike_new <- structure(list(yr = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mnth = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Ano = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L), cnt = c(985, 801, 1349, 1562, 1600, 2114, 3095, 1341, 
1796, 2729, 1085, 901, 1449, 1662, 1700)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

If you want to see only one line per year, a strategy could be that explained by **@Phil** using other variable as day. Or you can aggregate values in next form:

```
#Code 2
bike_new %>% 
  group_by(Ano,mnth) %>%
  summarise(cnt=sum(cnt,na.rm=T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(mnth),y=cnt,group=factor(Ano),color=factor(Ano)))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  xlab('month')+
  labs(color='Ano')
```

Output:

[image]

As you are analyzing number of bikes.

Comment: This output is not what I am looking for. I mean by a time series line chart, not those vertical lines

Comment: @insanedshk Please provide more data in order to help you!

Comment: @insanedshk The reason why those vertical lines appear is because the data shows the same months and years multiple times with a different count each time. If you want an actual time-series line chart, the data needs to include some kind of separator across the cases (presumably a day variable).

Comment: @insanedshk I have added an update with an strategy to get lines. Please let me know if that would work for you!